Как сделать так, чтобы курсор при нажатии tab в кавычках и в скобках перемещался вправо, как в PyCharm
Например ситуация
path("adf")

Нужно в конце, когда дописал adf, переместить курсор вправо 1 раз, дописать функцию и потом опять переместить курсор вправо, чтобы выйти из скобки, а до стрелок клавиатуры лень тянуть руку.
